# Java program keeps throwing up an error while compiling

Tags: java

```
EyeColour.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    Scanner input = scanner(System.in);
                    ^
  symbol:   method scanner(InputStream)
  location: class EyeColour
1 error
```

I keep getting this ^^ error when trying to compile the following code I'm new to Java and I can't find a solution online, sorry if the solution is really obvious:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class EyeColour // 
{
    public static void main (String[] param)
    {

        InputEye();
        System.exit(0);

     } // END main


    public static void InputEye()  
    {
        Scanner scanner = Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your eye colour?");
        String EyeColour;
        EyeColour = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("So your eyes are " + EyeColour + " are they? I like " + EyeColour);
        return;

    } // END InputEye  



} // END class EyeColour
```

Comment: Should be `new Scanner(System.in)`. You're missing the `new` keyword.

Comment: I believe you  could find the solution if you lookup any example on the web

Comment: You need `new` for new objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `new` keyword.
Try using this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```